# Get all values between two specific values in a list

Tags: c#, linq, char

I have a char list:

```
var myList = new List<char>(new[] { 'x', 'y', '(', 'a', 'b', 'c', ')', 'z' });
```

With the values:

```
 'x'
 'y'
 '('
 'a'
 'b'
 'c'
 ')'
 'z'
```

How can i take all the values between the braces? The values in new list should look like this:

```
 'a'
 'b'
 'c'
```

The index of the braces in the list can change every session.

Comment: The first thing you should have tried to do is plum this up with a `for` *loop*, great character building learning experience, and will give you sense of accomplishment. However you could also convert this to string and use regex, you could use IndexOf and all sorts of things.. however as it stands this questions shows a lack of research

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to get the index of of the first and second brace in the list with the method `IndexOf` and then use the `Take` method to take all the values between this indexes. I hoped there is something easier, for example using a linq.

Comment: @Nightscape If you tried something, specially if it worked, you have to put that code in the question, so we don't suggest you the same again

Comment: List do not guarantee the order when the data they contain do change.

Comment: I am sorry, I haven't coded my idea. It was just in my head. But still, next time i will add it to my question.

Comment: @bradbury9 do you have a source for that. So in my case in my original list the values could change the index.

Comment: @Nightscape If items are removed and added, the data behind could change its position. If you relay in a specific order you could get surprises in a future. Google the differences between List and [SortedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thats 100% true. Here is the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) behind `List<T>` . Yes it has an understanding of index : `public T this[int index] {`. But as it allow insert and remove, So it guarantee no order. If your code rely on the List been ordered. You either explicity sort or use an `IOrderedEnumerable` or a `SortedList`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this LINQ expression:

```
myList.SkipWhile(c => c != '(').Skip(1).TakeWhile(c => c != ')')
       ^----- 1 --------------^ ^- 2 -^ ^-------- 3 -----------^
```

1. Skip until we find the `(`
2. Skip past the `(` we found
3. Take elements until we find the `)` (which will not be included)

**Notes:**

1. If the sequence contains no starting parenthesis, an empty sequence will be returned
2. If the sequence contains no matching end parenthesis, the *rest of* the sequence will be returned

Comment: Nice solution! I like it because not only it is elegant and readable, but also conveys exactly what we want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop which took '[' (open bracket) if you found it then until you don't found close bracket ']' add character to another array.

Comment: I thought about that solution, I hoped there is something easier around for example with a linq.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in a few steps:

```
int start = myList.IndexOf('(') + 1;
int end = myList.IndexOf(')');
var result = myList.Skip(start).Take(end - start).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myList = new List<char>(new[] { 'x', 'y', '(', 'a', 'b', 'c', ')', 'z' });
var start = myList.FindIndex((c) => c == '(');
var end = myList.FindIndex((c) => c == ')');
if (start != -1 && end != -1 && start < end)
{
     var result = myList.GetRange(start + 1, end - start - 1));
}
else
{
    // return null or throw error
}
```